# Graphql spring boot client

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, graphql, client

guys, I have a problem: I have microservices on spring graphql, which works properly, example of request here:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wXwNm.png)

But it is not clear how to write client for the case if I need to convey list of objects. I tried to use GraphqlTemplate (implementation 'com.github.americanexpress:nodes:0.5.0') but I did not find any example of passing list to request. Maybe it worse to use other library.

Does anybody worked with something like that?

```
@Service
public class PersonService {

    private final GraphQLTemplate graphQLTemplate = new GraphQLTemplate();
    private final String url = "http://localhost:8084/graphql";
    
    
    public List<Person> getPersonsByIds() {
  
        GraphQLRequestEntity requestEntity;
        try {
            requestEntity = GraphQLRequestEntity.Builder()
                .url(url)
                .requestMethod(GraphQLTemplate.GraphQLMethod.QUERY)
                .request("query($personIds: [BigInteger]) {\n" +
                    "  getPersonsByIds(personIds : $personIds ) {\n" +
                    "    firstName\n" +
                    "    middleName\n" +
                    "    lastName\n" +
                    "    birthDt\n" +
                    "  }\n" +
                    "}"
                )
                .variables(new Variable<>("personId", "2477142261427744786")) // just enable to pass only one id and got 1 person
                .build();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        return graphQLTemplate.query(requestEntity, ResponseGetPersonsByIds.class).getResponse().getGetPersonsByIds();
    }    
}
```

I understand how to pass only 1 id but it is not clear how to pass the array

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you defined a schema for Person like this:

```
type Person{
    firstName: String
    // other fields...
}
```

Then you can use `@SchemaMapping` for returning list of that objects:

```
@SchemaMapping(typeName = "Query",value = "personList")
public List<Person> getPersonsByIds() {
  return personService.getPersonsByIds();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the DataFetchingEnvironment object to the resolver and call the getDocument() method to relay the document/query https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sILQm0axSw

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).